# Does the unix Curl command cache pages?

Tags: curl, cache, tor

I was using TOR and used an API called ipify. (https://api.ipify.org). I tried running the command `curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json' 2>&1 | grep -oP '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+'` while connected to tor and I got a TOR IP address as output. when I stopped my TOR proxy and tried running the same command in another terminal, I got my own IP address. However, running the command in the terminal I used first again resulted in the output being the TOR IP address, while I wasn't connected to TOR at all.

What is causing this?

Comment: `curl` doesn't cache pages, but there may be transparent caches along the way between the server and your machine.

Answer (score 1):

cURL does cache SSL sessions. You could try reproducing the behavior but calling cURL with

```
--no-sessionid
```

to see if you get a different result.